# Are DTMF tones decoded by the DTMF producer?

Tags: security, twilio, dtmf

If I generate a DTMF tone on phone A, clearly the tone gets decoded by the other phones (phone B, C...) on the call. Does the DTMF tone also get decoded by phone A?

How is the tone removed from the signal processing on phone A? Can I have the tone be interpreted by phone A?

Comment: Hi Sam, not sure what you're trying to get at here. Is this in a regular phone call? On what phone? You tagged Twilio, so I assume it's involved somehow, but you can you tell me how? I guess there is an ulterior motive to this, it might be helpful to share the overall question that you're trying to answer.

Comment: Hi Phil, This is actually on a home entry system system using Twilio. There's a kiosk that makes a call to a residents cellphone. The resident dials the dtmf tone 9, which unlocks the door. Could the visitor just dial 9? Or even play the tone for 9 loudly?

Comment: Are you trying to work out if the door could just open if the visitor was pressing the number? If you're using `<Gather>` to respond to the call within Twilio, then I don't believe a third party pressing a key would trigger the callback. I would have to test, but I guess it's possible that if you could play the tone for 9 loud enough that it was delivered though the resident's handset then that might trigger it, but that seems like an unlikely issue. To mitigate that somewhat, you could direct the resident to use a random digit or collection of digits each time?

Comment: This type of system is actually in pretty broad use already in many cities. Look up Door King Systems!

Comment: I don’t doubt that, it’s not a system I’ve used though and I’m just trying to help with your question. Are you closer to an answer yet?

Comment: I actually think you've answered the question Phil, basically, it seems possible but somewhat difficult due to the loudness of the tone!